# Show that the cardinality of $P(\mathbb{N})$ is $2^{\aleph_o}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, cardinals

Show that the cardinality of $P(\mathbb{N})$ - the power set of $\mathbb{N}$ - is $2^{\aleph_o}$.

Hint: Show that $P(\mathbb{N})$ has the same cardinality as the set $N = \{f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow A| f$ is a function$\}$, where $A = \{0, 1\}$.

My attempt:

Using an inductive argument with the statement that if $|X|=n$, then, $|P(X)| = 2^n$ for all $n\geq 0$, we have

Base: If $n = 0$, $X = \emptyset$. But the empty set is the only subset of itself, so $|P(X)| = 2^0$.

Inductive: Suppose for $m \geq 0$, if $|X| = m$, then $|P(X)| = 2^m$.

If $|X| = m + 1$, pick some $x \in X$ and let $Y = X - \{x\}$.

By assumption, $|P(Y)| = 2^m$.

There are two subsets of $X$: subsets with $x$ and subsets without $x$. For each subset, there are $2^m$ elements so $|P(X)| = 2P(Y) = 2^m + 2^m = 2^{m+1}$.

We have shown that the power set of a set $X$ has $2^{|X|}$ elements.

Let $X = \mathbb{N}$, then, as $|\mathbb{N}| = \aleph_o$, it follows that $|P(\mathbb{N})| = 2^{\aleph_o}$.

QED.

Is this proof correct? If so, what would a proof that uses the hint look like? Any insight is much appreciated.

Comment: You proved that $|\mathcal P(X)| = 2^{|X|}$ for any finite set $X$, but $\mathbb N$ is finite?

Comment: (instead, you should construct an explicit bijection between $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ and the set of functions $\mathbb{N} \to \{0,1\}$)

Comment: @diracdeltafunk I'm fairly new to such, so how exactly would I go about doing such a construction?

Comment: can we do exponentiation with cardinals? As according to my knowledge this is just a symbol

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi If $A$ and $B$ are sets, $A^B$ denotes the set of functions from $B$ to $A$. For cardinals, $\lvert A \rvert^{\lvert B \rvert}$ is defined to mean $\lvert A^B \rvert$.

Comment: that makes sense, thanks @diracdeltafunk

Comment: @Kraftsman Hint: having a function $\mathbb{N} \to \{0,1\}$ is the same as splitting the natural numbers into two (labelled) parts: the numbers that get sent to $0$, and the numbers that get sent to $1$. We want a procedure that takes a subset of $\mathbb{N}$, and produces a splitting-up of the naturals into two parts, in such a way that we can reconstruct the original subset if we're given these two parts.

Comment: If you are still stuck on diracdeltafunk's hint, consider that any subset of $\Bbb N$ also divides $\Bbb N$ into two parts: the numbers in the subset, and the numbers that are not.